# Can native UI overrides of select element be feature-detected?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, feature-detection

Many browsers display a select element's options in a simple box directly beneath the element like this:

[image: select regular]

But on Safari on iOS, for example, the choices are presented in a large native spinner like this:
[image: select iOS]

**Is there a way to feature-detect whether a browser will use a native UI for a select element instead of the "standard" UI?** I want conditionally display a select box to users with browsers where this is available, and I would prefer to not have to resort to user-agent sniffing.

Example credit: Gonçalo Morais

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is specifically designed as a "feature", like you were asking for. I'm fairly certain you will need to resort to user-agent detection because this is just how Safari on iOS chooses to *render* the element - to me it doesn't make sense for the Safari team to add an attribute to the SELECT element -or anywhere else on the DOM- to indicate this. That "feature" you were inquiring about is essentially the user-agent string.

You may know this, but for completion, I mention it here. There are many ways to achieve this - for instance, you can use Modernizr - adding custom tests to it to customise it further to your needs - see [this](https://coderwall.com/p/ktrbhq/detect-mobile-safari) as an example. Or use your own JavaScript. Or use JavaScript to add a specific class to the body or html elements indicating what browser it is so you can cascade down and customise your elements (essentially what Modernizr does).

I know this may not be the answer you were hoping for, but I'm pretty sure it is accurate for the most part. I would be very interested to hear different opinions tho.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :(  Oh well, thanks for your input.